# Module parse fail in next js zero-config

Tags: next.js

Next it seems doesn't handle the transpilation but according to documentation it should transpile all react components.

```
yarn run v1.15.2
$ next
[ wait ]  starting the development server ...
[ info ]  waiting on http://localhost:3000 ...
[ ready ] compiled successfully
[ info ]  ready on http://localhost:3000
[ event ] client pings, but there's no entry for page: /_error
[ event ] build page: /
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] C:/Users/danie/Documents/Projects/next-step/pages/index.js 5:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default () => {
|   return (
>     <div>
|       <p>Ciao</p>
|     </div>
[ event ] build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] C:/Users/danie/Documents/Projects/next-step/pages/index.js 5:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default () => {
|   return (
>     <div>
|       <p>Ciao</p>
|     </div>
```

The package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-step",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

And this is the component which should render.

```
// dummy component under /pages

import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It should renders a dummy page according to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was an environment issue in my user folder.
It was a global babel settings which interfered only with the nextjs package and it was sufficient delete the directory with that stored information.

Comment: Hey @danielo, can you say more in steps what you did? I tried with no luck to set up a basic nextjs app on windows following the tutorial from nextjs.org page and failed in the same way.

Comment: Hi. sorry for the delay. Take a look in your user folder (in windows C:\Users\<user>) and delete `.babel`  folder, is hidden. Then should it works again